# Getting empty directory after running meteor mongo dump command

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am trying to take dump of my mongo DB. As i am using meteor so i used the meteor command for taking dump i.e:-

```
mongodump -h 127.0.0.1 --port 3001 -d meteor
```

I also try to save the dump in a different location i.e:-

```
 mongodump -h 127.0.0.1 --port 3001 -d meteor  --out /home/parveen/Desktop/
```

But both time it will create a directory with name meteor and that directory is blank.
I am just wondering to know why this is happening because i tried the same command few months before that time i got the dump as expected. But now its not working, i guess that might be because of new meteor update.

would appreciate if anybody give me any answer or guess why is this happening.

Thanks

Comment: what database(s) you want to dump?

Comment: meteor DB that is created by Meteor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the answer why this is happening to me. Actually this issue is not related to meteor. **This is because of mongod version that is not updated . Once i upgrade my mongod version to v3.2.0** and after that i hit the above given command for mongo dump . Its create a directory and not blank directory this time with theDB files.

For checking the monngod version simply type:-

> mongod --version

**For upgarde your version of Mongod just do following:-**

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv EA312927
udo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org=3.2.0 mongodb-org-server=3.2.0 mongodb-org-shell=3.2.0 mongodb-org-mongos=3.2.0 mongodb-org-tools=3.2.0
```

Hope it will help!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to spin up meteor.

Then if you run

```
meteor mongo
```

you will get an output something like this:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.2.1
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:3001/meteor
```

Meteor DB host is at 127.0.0.1 with a port of 3001. Exit the mongo shell and use mongo dump from your terminal.

```
mongo dump -h 127.0.0.1 --port 3001 -d meteor
```

Dumps will be located under the dumps folder in the folder you executed the above command.

You can import your DB back to meteor with

```
mongorestore -h 127.0.0.1 --port 3001 -d meteor dump/meteor
```

Comment: i am doing the same dear  but getting blank directory with name meteor?