# Meteor - mongodump doesn't extract data - produces empty directory

Tags: mongodb, meteor, dump

I am running a local Meteor server on my machine, and I wanted to extract the mongoDB content, but for some reason its not working for me

The meteor server is up and running.

I run `meteor mongo` command to find out the port being used and it shows:

`MongoDB shell version: 3.2.12`

`connecting to: 127.0.0.1:3001/meteor`

So going back to shell, I run the following:

`mongodump -h  127.0.0.1 --port 3001 -d meteor`

the result on screen is :

`connected to: 127.0.0.1:3001
2017-05-10T18:23:43.686+0300 DATABASE: meteor    to     dump/meteor`

but the dump/meteor directory is empty.

Any help/guidance would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Update: I found out what the problem was, so I'm documenting it here for future reference.
It seems like there was a version missmatch between mongodb and the mongo tools. the mongodb version was 3.2 and the mongodump was 2.6 (mongodump --version).
in order to get the latest mongodump version I followed the instruction in https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-16-04 to add the latest MongoDB repository:

> Ubuntu ensures the authenticity of software packages by verifying that
>   they are signed with GPG keys, so we first have to import they key for
>   the official MongoDB repository.
>
> sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv
>   EA312927 After successfully importing the key, you will see:
>
> Output gpg: Total number processed: 1 gpg:               imported: 1 
>   (RSA: 1) Next, we have to add the MongoDB repository details so apt
>   will know where to download the packages from.
>
> Issue the following command to create a list file for MongoDB.
>
> echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.2
>   multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.2.list
>   After adding the repository details, we need to update the packages
>   list.
>
> sudo apt-get update

Then instead of installing the full mongoDB version (I already have 3.2 installed) I just installed the mongodb tools:
`sudo apt-get install mongodb-org-tools`

That solved the problem. Now mongodump command works as expected

Answer (score 1):

Use [RoboMongo](https://robomongo.org/) or [MongoBooster](https://mongobooster.com) to connect to your meteor db. Both these tools are great, but MongoBooster has some more features such as copying collections, exporting/import collections as json files, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer why this was happened to me. **Actually this issue is not related to meteor. This is because of mongod version that is not updated . Once i upgrade my mongod version to v3.2.0** and after that i hit the above given command for mongo dump . Its create a directory and not blank directory this time with theDB files.
For details visit my answer at :-

[Getting empty directory after running meteor mongo dump command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41438051/getting-empty-directory-after-running-meteor-mongo-dump-command/41585780#41585780)